# Symfony2 custom minimum age validator - no error message displayed in twig?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a minimum age custom validator which is straight forward enough:

**The constraint(Minage.php)**

```
namespace MyCompany\VisitBundle\Component\Validator\Constraints;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Minage extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The user must be {{ age }} or over';
    public $age = 18;

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return get_class($this).'Validator';
    }
}
```

**The validator (MinageValidator.php)**

```
namespace MyCompany\VisitBundle\Component\Validator\Constraints;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class MinageValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $minAge = strtotime(sprintf("-%s YEAR", $constraint->age));
        if(strtotime($value->format("Y-m-d")) > $minAge)
        {
            $this->setMessage($constraint->message,
                              array('{{ age }}' => $constraint->age));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**In my entity (stripping parts which aren't important)**

```
use MyCompany\VisitBundle\Component\Validator\Constraints as MyCompanyAssert;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="birth_date", type="datetime")
 * @MyCompanyAssert\Minage(age="18")
 */
private $birth_date;
```

**And in twig:**

```
{{ form_errors(form.birth_date) }}
{{ form_widget(form.birth_date) }}
```

I know for sure the validator is returning false but my form refuses to show the error message All other validators (out-of-the-box not custom) work fine and show their respective errors. Any idea?

Translations are disabled, so it won't be looking for a translation in a file.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE: `form_errors(form.birth_date)` does not work but `form_errors(form)` does? why is it assigned as a global form error?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of this behavior is error bubbling. Set the field's `error_bubbling` option to `false`.

Comment: Yups, that was the problem. Would have been nice if the form validation documentation mentioned this. it is however mentioned in the form field types section (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling) Thanks so much!

Comment: @Flukey, if the docs could be improved, please raise a ticket (or fork the docs and suggest an improvement if possible - I'm not sure for Symfony2).

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `$this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);` in `isValid` method of your validator.